# tvOS UITabBarController hides when its not focused

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I have implemented tabbarcontroller for tvOS top navigation and it hides when unfocused but my client has a requirement that tabbarController should be persistent when focused is moved out. Is it possible to keep tabbarController displayed persistently in tvOS?

Comment: There’s not a property. You’ll need to subclass and handle position based on focus events.

Answer (score 0):

The redesigned UITabBarController in tvOS 13 remains visible, if you don't implement any additional code to hide it.